# Filtering out elements in a weirdly structured list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a weirdly structure list of the format

```
mylist =[(['softwar', '3', 'instal', 'instruct'], 'read'), (['3', 'read', 'instruct', 'nis'], 'instal'), (['read', 'instal', 'nis', '2004'], 'instruct'), (['instal', 'instruct', '2004', 'nav'], 'nis'), (['instruct', 'nis', 'nav', '2004'], '2004'), (['nis', '2004', '2004', 'prior'], 'nav'), (['2004', 'nav', 'prior', 'latsni'], '2004'), (['nav', '2004', 'latsni', 'still'], 'prior'), (['2004', 'prior', 'still', 'end'], 'latsni'),........]
```

I want to filter out relevant words (that are in a list relevant_words) from mylist:

```
e.g 
relevant_words =['read','instal']
#I would want to just return:
[(['softwar', '3', 'instal', 'instruct'], 'read'),(['3', 'read', 'instruct', 'nis'], 'instal')]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

Comment: I was thinking of something like mylist[x][1] is in relevant_words

Comment: Why is your data so oddly structured

Comment: @jasonm its from a method i'm using from a library about term context in documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x, y in mylist if y in relevant_words]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['softwar', '3', 'instal', 'instruct'], ['3', 'read', 'instruct', 'nis']]
```

If you want to include the relevant words:

```
[(x,y) for x, y in mylist if y in relevant_words]
```

or

```
[x for x in mylist if x[1] in relevant_words]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(['softwar', '3', 'instal', 'instruct'], 'read'), (['3', 'read', 'instruct', 'nis'], 'instal')]
```

Comment: how could I also include the relevant word it is associated with at the end though, e.g [(['softwar', '3', 'instal', 'instruct'], 'read'),(['3', 'read', 'instruct', 'nis'],'instal')] (I'll edit the question now)

Comment: @Chris I know, I changed the question now, I do apologise